# CakePHP 3 : check date greater than today

Tags: datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an attribute `valid_till` of type `DATE`.

Now what I want to do is to compare `valid_till` from today's day.

```
$couponCheck = $this->Coupons->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
       'coupon_code' => $couponCode
     ]
   ]);
   if ($couponCheck->count() === 1) {
     $coupon = $couponCheck->first();
     if ($coupon->valid_till >= isToday()) {
        echo 'Coupon is Valid';
     } else {
        echo 'Coupon is Expired';
     }
   } else {
      echo 'This is not a valid coupon code';
   }
```

But this is not working. How could I do this ?

Comment: In case the coupon isn't bound to a specific time, you'd better store the expiration date as date only. That way the `valid_till` date object would have its time components properly set to `0`.

Comment: sorry for the mistyped `DATETIME`, its `DATE` only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`valid_till` should already be a date/time object, depending on your CakePHP version and configuration, by default either `\Cake\I18n\Time`, `\Cake\I18n\Date`, or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate`, backed by either Carbon or Chronos.

If you're on CakePHP >= 3.2, then you should have a `\Cake\I18n\Date` or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` object, and you should be able to simply check the validity using `isPast()`, like

```
if (!$coupon->valid_till->isPast()) {
    echo 'Coupon is Valid';
} else {
    echo 'Coupon is Expired';
}
```

For earlier versions you'd have to check against today too, like

```
!$coupon->valid_till->isPast() || $coupon->valid_till->isToday()
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Date & Time](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Immutable Dates and Times](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#immutable-dates-and-times)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Enabling Immutable DateTime Objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#enabling-immutable-datetime-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > Chronos > Comparison Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html#comparison-methods)**
- **[Carbon Docs > Comparison](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison)**

Comment: Thanks for the simplest answer. I'm on CakePHP 3.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$valid_till = $coupon->valid_till;
$dt = new DateTime($valid_till);

$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
if ($date >= date('Y-m-d')) {
echo 'Coupon is Valid';
} else {
echo 'Coupon is Expired';
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But with little change in 2nd line to `$dt = new Time($valid_till);`. About code gives error as `Class 'App\Controller\datetime' not found`. I have used `use Cake\I18n\Time;` in the controller and this is working.

Comment: Thanks @ndm for sharing this.

Comment: `valid_till` should already be a time object, which could easily be checked using the methods provided by Chronos/Carbon. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html** @anujsharma9196